# Gradle sourceSets

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle

using gradle with below sourceSets :

```
sourceSets{
    main{
        output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/java/main")
    }
}
```

according to https://docs.gradle.org/4.0-rc-2/release-notes.html
i still having the error :

*Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0*

Please help, my tomcat serer runs overall, but i like to get rid with this message.

Here my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets{
    main{
        output.classesDir = new File(buildDir, "classes/java/main")
    }
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8 
version = '1.0'  

ext {
    javaVersion     = 1.8
    springVersion   = '4.3.10.RELEASE'
    aspectjVersion  = '1.8.10'
    slf4jVersion    = '1.7.25'
}



dependencies {

    compile (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: springVersion){
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion

    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: aspectjVersion

    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: slf4jVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: slf4jVersion
    compile (group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17') {
        exclude group: 'javax.mail', module: 'mail'
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
    }
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0' 
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.1' 
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '8.5.16'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.5.2",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Opal please find my added gradle file on original message